# Change language/texts of ImagePicker

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4, imagepicker

How can I change the language or texts of messages/buttons of ImagePicker (https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/image-picker) in Android and iOS?

My device language is pt-br, but texts are shown in english.. I need to show in portuguese

Thanks

Comment: I believe that the plugin does not have translations for Portuguese https://github.com/Telerik-Verified-Plugins/ImagePicker/tree/master/src/android/Library/res You could create them yourself and submit a pull request.

Comment: @RaulSauco Hi, there is a pull request for that (https://github.com/Telerik-Verified-Plugins/ImagePicker/pull/157).. I tried to create the same pull request files locally in the plugin directory, but it didn't work ... I don't know if it's possible to do that as a workaround